# Q-learning with clustered time series

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis, q-learning

I am new to Q-learning, and I recently tried to apply this algorithm to a problem with 9 states and 2 possible actions. I am considering a big number of time series, each of which has only 10 data points, and want to choose between two actions at time t=10. The problem is that matrix Q has not been updated yet for most states, leading to a random decision.

I was considering clustering the time series and getting an averaged Q for each cluster, from which I would choose an action based on the state of each particular series.

The question is whether taking the mean of multiple Q matrices could make sense or if there is any other approach that could be more suitable in this case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you provide a little more information? What is the reward structure? In addition, it is not clear to me the relation between the time series and the states. Could you clarify that too?

Comment: For each product, I have 4 time series A, B, C and D. Their (simplified) meaning is the following:

A: simple forecast of time series C
B: alternative forecast of time series C
C: actual value of the series
D: more expensive but (theoretically) more accurate forecast of time series C

Comment: The state is defined comparing A and B with C (for instance, if A is more than 10% over the value of C and B is less than 10% below the value of C, the state would be "+-"). If A is close to C and B is more than 10% over the value of C, the state would be "0+". So there is a total of 9 states corresponding to all possible combinations.

Comment: There are two possible actions: choosing series A or choosing series D in order to forecast C. If A is chosen, the reward is -abs((A-C)/C) and if D is chosen, the reward is -abs((D-C)/C).